# Dropdown values while creating a case

Tags: php

I am using the below query

$query="SELECT
                Account.Name,
                AccountId, Add_Phone__c, AssistantName, AssistantPhone, Birthdate, Call_Phone__c, CreatedById, 
                CreatedDate, Department, Description, Edit_Home_Phone__c, Edit_Mobile__c, Edit_Other_Phone__c, Email, 
                EmailBouncedDate, EmailBouncedReason, Fax, FirstName, HasOptedOutOfEmail, Home_Phone__c, HomePhone, Id, 
                IsDeleted, Jigsaw, JigsawContactId, LastActivityDate, LastCURequestDate, LastCUUpdateDate, 
                LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastName, LeadSource, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode, 
                MailingState, MailingStreet, MasterRecordId, Mobile_Calculated__c, MobilePhone, Name, Other_Phone__c, 
                OtherCity, OtherCountry, OtherPhone, OtherPostalCode, OtherState, OtherStreet, 
                LastModifiedBy.Name,CreatedBy.Name,Owner.Email, Owner.Id, Owner.Name, Owner.Phone, Owner.Title,
                OwnerId, Phone,
                Phone_calculated__c, ReportsToId, Salutation, SystemModstamp, TIMBASURVEYS__Survey__c, Title,
                (SELECT Name,Id,CreatedDate,Status FROM Assets),
                (SELECT Id,fprot_key_1__c,fprot_key_2__c,IP_Address__c,CreatedDate,Name,email__c FROM fprot__r), 
                (SELECT CaseNumber,Id,Subject,Priority,CreatedDate,Status,OwnerId FROM Cases), 
                (select Name,Id, ContractNumber, EndDate, StartDate, Status,Owner.Name from ServiceContracts),
                (SELECT Name,Id,CreatedDate,Item_Name__c,Payer_Status__c,Payment_Date__c,Payment_Gross__c,
                   Payment_Type__c,Payment_Status__c,Transaction_Subject__c,Txn_Type__c FROM Paypal__r)
                FROM Contact where  id='003d000001bLH7I'";
$response = $this->sCon->query($query);
        echo "";
        print_r($response);
        exit();

Here I am not getting fields from  the servicesContract table while the same query returning one records of servicecontract table.
I don't know the exact problem i am using PHPToolkit

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [PHP Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit), then you can use the DescribeSObject of Enterprise service to get the picklist values of the field.

Here's [sample code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_DescribeSObject_Sample_(Enterprise)) from salesforce docs which has some code with request & response

Comment: i have already used DescribeSObject as below
$response = $this->sCon->describeSObjects(array('Case'));
And it gives the same structure result as you gave me the example but my problem is that i want some specific records for example when we select a value from the RecordType then it takes some value.I am unable to understand that how can i change the values of dropdown fields when a user select a recordType from previous step?

Comment: I am getting these values �� in the Validfor field .How can i decode it using php?